# How to extract files from a merged file

Tags: awk, extract

I want to separate a merged file into two files. The file:

```
file.dat

i =100
1 2 3
i =1
-1 -2 -3
i =101
1 2 3
i =102
1 2 3
i =103
1 2 3
i =2
-1 -2 -3 
....
```

The mixed indices are

```
1,2,3,4, ...,99
```

and

```
100, 101, 102, 103,...,200.
```

The indices appear alternately, but there is no rule.
The data

```
1 2 3
```

and

```
-1 -2 -3
```

just denote the data block in each step.

Could you give an idea to separate the merged file into two files with respect to the indices?

Comment: do you want to sort data by index? (this is a multi-line record problem)

Comment: Thanks for reply! I want to separate the file into two files. Each one are with the index line "i=..".

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: @Jidder The output is expected to be `i=100 \n 1 2 3 \n i=101 \n 1 2 3 ...` and  `i=1 \n -1 -2 -3 \n i=2 \n -1 -2 -3  ...`  @Mark Setchell Mark Setchell's answer does not directly include the `i=..` line. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Do they need to be on the same line ?

Comment: @Jidder No, they don't. But I hope to find how can the lines `i=**` can be included in the output. Since each block includs multiple lines, it 's better to keep the `i=**` lines.

Comment: Just use `awk -F= '/^i/{x=$2<100?"a.txt":"b.txt"}{print>x}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the data blocks appended to two different files, depending on which group of indexes it belongs to, this should work:

```
# separate.awk

{
  if ($1 == "i")
  {
    split($2,a,"=");
    i = a[2];
  }

  if (i < 100)
    print > "1-99.dat";
  else
    print > "100-200.dat"
}
```

---

```
$ awk -f separate.awk file.dat

$ cat 1-99.dat
i =1
-1 -2 -3
i =2
-1 -2 -3 

$ cat 100-200.dat
i =100
1 2 3
i =101
1 2 3
i =102
1 2 3
i =103
1 2 3
```

Comment: for this output you can literally just use `awk '{f="1-99.dat"}/1 2 3/{f="100-200.dat"}{print >f}' file`

Comment: I am guessing that the real data blocks are not all the same, and contain something more interesting than "1 2 3".

Comment: @Pontus  It's true that `1 2 3` denotes more.  What if we want to keep the `i=**` line before each block? I find it is not possible to add it before each block? Thanks.

Comment: @jiadong Updated the code to include the "i=**"-headers in the output files. I simply removed the "else"-block so all lines are written to the output files.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should do it for you:

```
awk -F= '/=/{f="a.txt";if($2>99)f="b.txt";next} {print >f}' file.dat
```

First, it sets the field separator to `=`. Then it checks if the line contains an equals sign, and if so, it is time to set the name of the output file to either "a.txt" or "b.txt" depending on the number after the equals sign. Then on subsequent records we just write to the file we last selected.

Comment: Why have you changed the filenames just to make your code shorter ?

Comment: @Jidder Huh? I didn't see any specification of what the filenames are required to be - I just made them up! I was demonstrating the `technique` rather than providing a quality-controlled, independently-verified solution :-)

Comment: Yeah i read the other answer and thought they were the filenames, woops my bad :(

Comment: Actually, you could have made it even shorter! `awk -F= '/=/{f=$2>99?"b.txt":"a.txt";next}{print>f}' file.dat`

Comment: @Pontus Yes, I thought about that, but didn't want to obfuscate my answer with the less well-known ternary operator - but I agree with you absolutely.

Comment: @Pontus - That'd be `f=($2>99?"b":"a")".txt"` to avoid redundantly specifying the `.txt` suffix twice. You also need the parens as ternary expressions will cause syntax errors in some contexts on some awks without them.  @MarkSetchell - IMHO ternary expressions should be used when appropriate. If people don't understand them they need to get over it and learn how to use them - they're just one more useful coding construct. +1

Comment: @EdMorton I agree, your ternary looks better. It should probably be added that one-liners can actually be quite readable, with a little whitespace and descriptive variable names. It's usually not a good idea to make them quite this dense.

Comment: @Pontus right. conciseness is a desirable quality of software, not brevity alone. Software is like a diamond in that there's 4 "c"s to consider but instead of cut, color, clarity, and carat it's cohesion, coupling, conciseness, and conformity.